# Is it appropriate to post 1k+ lines of code?

Tags: discussion

I recently asked a [question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/25155/is-this-method-doing-too-much) on CR, and got an interesting suggestion that I'd like to look into. However, due to the class that the method is part of, and me still being green, I'm having a hard time trying to make this work for my whole class. There are 1.2k+ lines in my class. I'd read other meta questions where it was deemed some responses was to "break up the code" for multiple reviews. However, as is in my case, sometimes that won't be helpful. So, would it be appropriate to post an entire class, even if it's more than 1k lines? 2k? At what point do we define excess?

Comment: I would suggest that you refactor the class first. Then  it will be much easier for you to ask for a review for just some parts of your code.

Comment: Refactor it to what? I mean, isn't this the point of CR, for reviewing code and ideas on making it better?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I'm thinking that 1.2k lines is a probably a bit much. You probably hit a limit on the size of posts before then.

In cases where the code is too large, the recommended approach is to post part of the code, and then to link to the rest of the code offsite. Anybody who is interested can look at the rest of your code, but they'll focus on what you post. So I suggest that you post a few methods, preferably some related ones from the class.

For something like that you'll probably get some pointers on ideas for getting started on the refactoring process to tame that huge class.