# What is the recommended length of the code for review?

Tags: support, scope, asking-questions, code-length, character-limit

I have code that is about 1000 lines long (and growing, as some features are not yet implemented and some edge cases unhandled), so posting it here likely would overwhelm people, even if it would be bountied.

What would be a good strategy? Extract some function that is especially likely to be improvable? And link the entire code. And once processed - maybe ask again to help with another code segment?

Rewrite it to remove functionality and reduce length? And later use review suggestions in the real project?

Or is 1500 or 2000 lines script still reasonable? Maybe it would be better to post it in parts with individual functions for review?

Maybe try with entire one in the faint hope of someone helping and once that fails post smaller segments? In the reverse order?

I found [Is it appropriate to post 1k+ lines of code?](https://codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/706/is-it-appropriate-to-post-1k-lines-of-code/707#707) - but given that it was posted 9 years ago maybe community has changed opinion a bit.

Comment: "maybe community has changed opinion a bit." No, feel free to post all the code. "some features are not yet implemented" asking us to implement them would be off-topic, but if you just say "I've not finished X, Y and Z don't review them" then you should be all clear. One tip; don't split up your code into multiple code blocks. Just have one code block for your code.

Comment: @Peilonrayz "asking us to implement them would be off-topic" oh definitely - I meant that I planned to implement that before posting - rather than post code littered with `FIXME` `HACK` `TODO` and `//wait, why [0] is needed here`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The community likes lots of code, it allows us to do a good review. You might notice some delay in getting an answer because a lot of code takes time to review the code. If you look at my questions, none of them are short. I've had to break some of my code into multiple questions to get all of it into Code Review. All of my questions have been answered, sometimes it takes a week to get an answer.

Many programs in questions on this site are trivial, the best questions are not.